# How to get an input function for an array to terminate based upon a specific input and size?

Tags: c, arrays, input, infinite-loop

I have an input function for an array that is initialized to contain 50 elements.  The loop that is collecting input from the user terminates once the value "-1" is entered and 50 entries are entered in.

In order to test the program correctly I have these 2 test cases:

1. There are less than 50 values entered and the data set ends with "-1".
2. There are 50 values entered and the data set doesn't end with a "-1".

I'm able to get the 1st test case to work, but for the 2nd test case it appears to go into an infinite loop.  How would I modify my input function to work for the 2nd test case as well?

Main Function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//Global Declarations
#define SIZE 50

int getFuelRange();
int getStartMile();
void getMileMarkers(int markers[], int*);
void bubbleSort(int markers[], int);
int searchArray(int markers[], int, int);
int calcDifference(int markers[], int, int, int);
int findSize(int markers[]);
//void displayResults();

int main()
{
  //Local Declarations
  int fuelRange;
  int startMile;
  int markers[SIZE];
  int i = 0;
  int points;
  int size;

  //Executable Statements
  fuelRange = getFuelRange();
  startMile = getStartMile();
  getMileMarkers(&markers[i], &size);
  //Diagnostics
  //printf("\nFuel Range: %d Start Mile: %d\n", fuelRange, startMile);
  //printf("\nSize: %d \n", size);
  points = calcDifference(&markers[i], fuelRange, startMile, size);


  //Diagnostics
  //printf("\nFuel Range: %d Start Mile: %d\n", fuelRange, startMile);
  printf("Points: %d \n", points);

  return(0);
}
```

Input Function:

```
void getMileMarkers(int markers[], int *size)
{
  //LOCAL DECLARATIONS
  int i = -1; //counter
  //EXECUTABLE STATEMENTS
  printf("Enter mile marker positions: ");
  do
  {
    i++;
    scanf("%d", &markers[i]);
    //Diagnostic Print
    printf("\n%d", markers[i]);
  }while(markers[i] != -1 && i < SIZE);
  (*size) = i;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much easier and more readable to just have a do-loop and exit if the marker is found:

```
for ( i=0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
   scanf("%d", &markers[i]);
   if ( markers[i] == -1 ) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: My only issue is that I can't use a break statement, so could I just replace that by setting i = SIZE?